# Export Website Code to txt file

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if it is possible to make an application or script or etc, that could export the html code of websites that I visit on my browser. If so, please let me know what language could take a care of this job and if I need resources such as an api. For example I would enter the address of a website in the address bar of my web browser and while it loads there is something that saves the source code of the webpage I visited to a file. Thank you.

Comment: You can probably do it in any language - though you might want a third party library to parse the HTML(so you can tell what JavaScript and CSS files the page needs and get them too). What languages do you know best?

Comment: C++, Actionscript 3.0, HTML, Javascript (sorry for late reply)

Answer (score 3):

The capability is built right in. From your browser, while visiting the site you want to export, do one of the following:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Mac OSX: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: (sorry for late reply) Not like that. I want it to automatically get exported every time I visit webpage. For example I open my browser and google something. While it loads, the webpage's source would get transferred to a txt file. And again, I click on another link and the source code of that website automatically get transferred to a txt file.